# How to read string of more than 1024 characters from Xcode stdin in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, limit, stdin

I want to read string from Xcode stdin with length more than 1024 characters, is it possible? here is my code but doesn't work.

```
    size_t length;
    char *chars = fgetln(stdin, &length);
    NSString  *str = [NSString stringWithCString:chars encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    str = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Xcode never returns after the 3rd line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin,
This is a limit of the OS, not NSString.

Check out this post, where they discuss CAT versus PBPASTE

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3852

Larry